# Why are "smooth" varieties so defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, affine-varieties, motivation

The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves by *Joseph H. Silverman* defines a **smooth** (or non-singular) variety as follows:

> Let $V$ be a variety, $P\in V$, and $f_1, \ldots, f_m \in \overline{K}[X]$ a set of generators for $I(V)$. Then, $V$ is non-singular (or smooth) at $P$ if the $m\times n$ matrix
> $$\left(\frac{\partial f_i(P)}{\partial X_j} \right)_{1\le i\le m\\ 1\le j\le n}$$ has rank $n - \dim V$. If $V$ is nonsingular at every point, then we say that $V$ is
> nonsingular (or smooth).

Note that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f_i(P)}{\partial X_j}$ have nothing to do with analysis; they are just formal expressions.

Where does the above definition come from? Does it have something to do with partial derivatives in analysis? I can't help but believe so due to the very suggestive notation used by the author. Thank you!

---

- An affine algebraic set $V$ in $\Bbb A^n$, we define the ideal of $V$ as $$I(V) := \{f\in \overline{K}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]: f(P) = 0\quad \forall P\in V\}$$
- $\dim V$ is the transcendence degree of $\overline{K}(V)$ over $\overline{K}$. Here, $K(V)$ is the quotient field of $K[V]$, the affine coordinate ring of $V/K$.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$ you can define a functor from smooth varieties to complex manifolds called analytification. For example the analytification of a smooth projective curve of genus $g$ is a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$. It's not at all accurate to say that the partial derivatives "have nothing to do with analysis"; again, over $\mathbb{C}$ they are (complex) derivatives in the usual sense.

Comment: "Have nothing to do with analysis" is a bit strong. They do coincide with the analytical derivatives when that makes sense.

Comment: Have a look at these notes: https://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/09-10/Spring/18.726/l_8.pdf. Being smooth means that the tangent space has the right dimension. This tangent space can be identified with the kernel of the Jacobian matrix you describe: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675773/how-to-think-of-the-zariski-tangent-space.

Comment: The key notion, which no one has mentioned, is the *implicit function theorem*. In the setting of multivariable calculus, this gives submanifolds of euclidean space, which are the smooth analogue of what you're thinking about.